# Vertical alignment of text in a button with icon is not correct

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I have been trying to make a twitter clone, while making the sidebar I am not able to align the text of "Home" and "Explore". in img you can see "Home" is little bit towards the right. while inspecting I found that faHome icon is of 18x14 size, while faHashtag is of 14x14.

I need to know how I can I keep all button's text and Icon in same alignment.
Following the code for complete screen as shown in image. I am using Tailwind CSS

```
 <div className="flex flex-row">

{--------- Div for Nav Bar ---------}
        <div class="px-4 w-80 bg-white flex flex-col justify-start align-center top-0 bottom-0 left-0 fixed">
          <div>
            <button className="flex p-4 bg-red-500 mb-2 rounded-full mx-auto 2xl:mx-0 2xl:space-x-4 focus:outline-none hover:text-blue hover:bg-blue hover:bg-opacity-20">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} className="mr-4 text-xl" />

              <span>Home</span>
            </button>

            <button className="flex p-4 bg-red-500 rounded-full mx-auto 2xl:mx-0 2xl:space-x-4 focus:outline-none hover:text-blue hover:bg-blue hover:bg-opacity-20">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHashtag} className="mr-4 text-xl" />

              <span>Explore</span>
            </button>

            <button className="flex p-4 rounded-full mx-auto 2xl:mx-0 2xl:space-x-4 focus:outline-none hover:text-blue hover:bg-blue hover:bg-opacity-20">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHashtag} size="lg" className="mr-4" />
              <span>Explore</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

{---------------------}


        <div className="flex-auto h-screen bg-blue-400">Hello World</div>
        <div className="w-96 h-screen bg-gray-400">Hello World</div>
      </div>
```

[image]

**I want Home and explore to look something like this.**

[image]

Comment: You could assign a fixed `width` to the `FontAwesomeIcon` elements or wrap it into another element with a fixed `width`. In your case it should be `width: 18px`.

Comment: @majusebetter it's doesn't help

Comment: What exactly did you try? You can have a look at this little example using a wrapper for the actual icon. I simulated the different icon sizes by assigning different `width` attributes to the `img` tag. If you comment in the `width: 24px` in the CSS section, the problem should be solved: https://jsfiddle.net/aLmspfo4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was there because of icons size coming from FontAwesome Icons. though I tried to wrap the size into a div, but that didn't work.

I found out that we can use following to get the desired size of icon.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon  icon={faHome}  style={{ width: "20px", height: "230px" }}  />
```